# How do I disable DVD auto eject in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, optical-drive

I just discovered an incredibly annoying "feature" of Windows 7 tonight.  If you click on your optical drive in Explorer, and there is no disc in the drive, Windows 7 is kind enough to open the tray for you.  I'm finding it hard to contain my rage over this idiotic design decision.  WTF?

According to [this post](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/03/14/how-to-easily-disable-cd-or-dvd-auto-eject-in-windows-vista/), this behavior was apparently introduced in Vista.  The author posted a workaround, but I don't want a workaround.  I want it to stop doing this.  Like he, I have a case with a door that covers the drive bays.  If it's closed, and I accidentally click on that optical drive, it knocks on that door 10 or 12 times before giving up.

Can this behavior be turned off in Windows 7?

Comment: Why do you double click on the drive if there's nothing in it? :)

Comment: Ha I never noticed that before in Vista. @alex I always assumed that you can browse the optical drive to drag-drop files for burning, if it's a DVD writer that is, even without media. I'm very confused as to why it doesn't support this anymore, did I just dream that? Strange indeed.

Comment: @alex: It doesn't even require a double click.  A single click will do when you click on the drive in the folder tree.

Comment: On my PC it only works with a double click. I tried it this morning, after reading your question; a single click does nothing.

Comment: This is incredibly annoying. I totally agree about this being a completely stupid design decision. +1 for the question/answer. Unfortunately I did use the built-in Windows burning functionality, and now I can't.

Comment: @alex, it depends on whether the single-click–activation function of Explorer is on or not. Besides, you could double-click it by accident, or think there is a disc in that has no icon or volume-label, or simply press `Enter` by accident on it while trying to navigate to a different volume (remember that not everybody has *My Computer* configured to display the same way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try disabling the Windows built-in burn functionality. Apparently, this will also stop the auto-eject feature. You can read more about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110307025057/http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/02/20/windows-vista-cddvd-optical-drive-auto-eject-or-open-feature/).

Comment: His statement, "Only DVD RW drive will auto eject and open when clicked on its icon. DVD-ROM drive won’t has the effect." is **wrong**.  I just tried it on a computer here at work that has a DVD-ROM drive (*not* a burner) and it popped right open.

Comment: However, his instructions for removing the CD burning features did the trick.

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me on Windows 7 (but how stupid that you have to disable useful functionality to get rid of this ridiculous annoyance).

Comment: `I just tried it on a computer here at work that has a DVD-ROM`   @raven, exactly! Someone in [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-change-auto-eject-when-dvdcd-rom-is/b357e1cd-9211-40ac-8310-16eaede08c74) tried to explain the reasoning behind the behavior, but it only seems to affect laptops, not desktops, so as another person said, the rationale is bogus.

Comment: your link is dead, here's [an alternative](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5942-burning-cd-dvd-enable-disable.html) and [a superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/365651/how-do-you-keep-the-dvd-drive-from-opening-when-you-get-the-message-please-inse) about it

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to disable CD/DVD ROM from the Device Manager. But you have to re-enable when you're going to use it.