# Prevent CD-ROM from Opening

Tags: windows-7

When the CD-ROM drive is selected in Windows Explorer, the drive ejects.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Wow.  Interesting.  I never noticed that before.  Guess I've never selected the CD device inside explorer!

Answer (score 2):

See this very (exactly?) similar question:

[How do I disable DVD auto eject in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56017/how-do-i-disable-dvd-auto-eject-in-windows-7)

Apparently by disabling the auto-burn feature, you also disable the auto-eject feature:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/02/20/windows-vista-cddvd-optical-drive-auto-eject-or-open-feature/

some info in other answers came from here:
http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/b357e1cd-9211-40ac-8310-16eaede08c74

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of getting around the issue:

1. Always leave a disc inside the drive permanently so that whenever you accidentally click on the drive, it opens the contents of the drive rather than ejecting it.
2. As a sidenote, you can configure the folder options to respond to a double click and not to a single click. The odds of accidentally double-clicking on a CD/DVD drive are far less compared to a single click. Do this in case you have single click configured for Folder Options.

Here’s how:

a) Go to Start, type Folder Options and press Enter.

b) Select the option Double-click to open an item (single-click to select).

c) Click Apply.

d) Click Ok.