# How do you keep the DVD drive from opening when you get the message "please insert a disk into drive"?

Tags: windows-7, dvd

In Windows Explorer, when I click on the drive that happens to be my cd/dvd drive, I get the message "please insert a disk into drive", which might be OK, but then the DVD drive opens and I have to close it. I consider this very rude and I do not like it. Is there a way I can keep the DVD drive from opening when it is empty and Windows tries to access it?

Comment: This is a charming question. :) I know of a few ways to stop this behavior, however they each involve disabling one built-in feature or another. If you do not use the built-in Windows disc burning feature, then I have an answer.

Comment: No, I don't use Windows for disc burning, and I would also like to get rid of that stupid desktop.ini that is always waiting to be burned (in Windows Explorer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can effectively stop the 'rude' auto eject behavior by disabling the built-in CD burning settings.

### Quick Solution:

- Set the following value in the **Registry**:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoCDBurning"=dword:00000001
```

---

### Solution:

- Open the **Local Group Policy Editor** (`gpedit.msc`).

  [image: Run]
- Navigate to `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Explorer`.
- Find and **double click** the `Remove CD Burning features` setting.

  [image: Settings]
- Change the setting to `Enabled`, and **click** `Okay`.

  [image: Enabled]
- **Log off** and then log back in.

---

### Before:

- Context menu (notice the `Burn to disc` option).

  [image: Burn to disc]
- When we double click the drive, this message pops up **and** the disc tray pops open. **>:(**

  [image: Insert disc]

### After:

- **CD Burning** has been disabled. *(The `Format...` option is gone, too...)*

  [image: CD burning disabled]
- When we double click the drive, the disc tray **does not** eject! **:D** *(I don't know why they changed the spelling of 'disc'...)*

  [image: Insert disk]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! (There's no group policy editor on my system, so I used the reg file here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5942-burning-cd-dvd-enable-disable.html)

Comment: Ah. Yes. The Group Policy Editor changes the same registry value. I will update my answer to include that method. It's strange that there is no setting for disabling just the auto eject behavior.

Comment: Note that in Windows 10, you need to look for the `Remove CD Burning Features` entry under `File Explorer`, not `Windows Explorer`.